# How to find MAC address of a machine in my network

Tags: mac-address

At work, we have a network with internal [IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) given to machines. How can I find the MAC address of machines in my network whose IP address is known to me?

Also how do I find the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of my router whose IP address I know?

I work on [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erm, arping isn't needed.  You can just use arp.

`arp <ipaddress>`

same thing with your gateway.  `netstat -rn` to find your gateway then `arp <ipaddress>`, use `arp -i <device> <ipaddress>` if you want to force a specific interface.

you probably also want to use the `-c 4` arguments if you decide to use `arping`.

After all is said and done you can simply type `arp -a` to get your current ARP table.  another reason arping isn't ideal is that it's not installed by default on many systems.

Answer (score 2):

Use `arping` as superuser:

```
sudo arping -I<interface> <IP>
```