# Obtain MAC Address from network printer via CMD

Tags: cmd.exe, network-printer, mac-address

I'm trying to find the MAC address for my network printer using cmd.

I've tried using nbtstat -a (ipaddress) and it says host not found.  But the IP works when I ping it.  Is there another command that can pull the information for me?

Comment: Is the printer on the same layer-2 LAN and layer-3 network as your PC?

Comment: if they are on same network you can do:
arp -a|find "x.x.x.x"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find MAC address of a machine in my network](http://superuser.com/questions/290927/how-to-find-mac-address-of-a-machine-in-my-network)

Comment: I found a much easier way. I ping the device and then after enter ARP -A and it gives me even more information than I needed. BTW, arp -a|find is not a valid command

Comment: @awoitte Rubbish. `arp -a|find "dynamic"` works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, if you know the printer's IP address, you can use "ping" and "arp /a" to find the same information.  You will need to do some searching.  If you don't mind clearing your DNS cache with "ipconfig /flushdns" the list will be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I used nbtstat -a as well. If you know the IP of the printer you can do nbtstat -a {IP address}, without the brackets of course :). It'll kick back the MAC address of the device associated with that IP

Comment: OP stated in the question that using `nbtstat -a <IP>` returns "host not found", advising to run that command is probably not going to help. If you have any other advice, feel free to edit your answer to include these information!

Comment: The command may work if the device utilizes [NetBIOS over TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP#Nbtstat). I.e., you will likely see the MAC address in the output if the system uses that networking protocol, but, if it doesn't, which is likely if the system is a printer, then relying on `nbtstat -a ip_address` to obtain the MAC address is not the best way to obtain that address. Instead, he could just ping the IP address and then examine the [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) cache with `arp -a` or `arp -a | find "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`.